# Which exception should be thrown from a transactional method according to JTA standard?

Tags: java, exception, rollback, jta

Let us say that we develop some custom JTA implementation.

Consider the following method:

```
@Transactional
public void foo() {
   em.save(...); // some interaction with EntityManager
   throw new IllegalStateException("Foo");
}
```

Let us say that `em.save(...)` works fine without throwing an exception. So we always end up with `throw new IllegalStateException("Foo")`. It is clear that transaction should be rolled back in this case.

The question is: in runtime, according to JTA standard, should invocation of the `foo()` method throw a `RollbackException` or the original `IllegalStateException`?

In other words:

```
try {
   foo();
} catch (Exception e) {
   // What type of exception we should expect here?
}
```

My personal point of view is that the original exception (`IllegalStateException("Foo")` in this case) should be expected. However I would like to receive some answer strictly based on JTA documentation or other conventional contracts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation of `RollbackException` (https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/RollbackException.html) mentions:

> Thrown by the persistence provider when EntityTransaction.commit() fails.

In your case, `EntityTransaction.commit()` should never called, so this exception shall not be thrown.